# Run-time vs. Compile-time in programming

Tags: java, compiler-construction

I want to know details about difference between run-time and compile-time. And what is run-time errors and compile-time errors? What are the differences between them?

Comment: The names dont give you any clues?

Comment: Do some of your own research and come back with a specific question. https://www.google.com/search?num=20&safe=off&site=&source=hp&q=runtime+vs+compile+time

Answer (score 3):

Compile-time exceptions or errors are mistakes in your code that are obvious to the compiler that will create a broken program. Any IDE worth its salt will automatically mark these errors for you and won't even try to build.

Run-time exceptions are mistakes in your code that are not necessarily invalid code but when the program is run it leads to a state where things don't add up, illegal operations are attempted or some variable is `null` when something tries to use it. IDEs may or may not pick up on these mistakes and they are by far the harder type to track down. This is where getting used to using a debugger is incredibly important.

In summary:
compile-time: when trying to build/compile your code
run-time: when using already built code.

Answer (score 0):

A run-time error is a type of error that occurs post compilation.  Lets say you have a loop that iterates through an array.  But your logic is a little off and you accidentally go out of bounds (IndexOutOfBoundsException), the compiler doesn't know that this is going to happen because it doesn't look for logical errors caused by the programmer or user in this way.  NullPointerExceptions caused by null references are another runtime error.  A compile-time error could be a syntax error; missing semi-colon for example.

You should read this article if you want to know about checked and unchecked exceptions, http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=129

It has an explanation of the difference between checked and unchecked exceptions which may help you understand the differences between the types of exceptions and the causes of them.

In terms of code invokation, most of it is done at compile time.  When you instantiate an object, or call it's method.  This is all compiled into instructions and are prepared at compile-time.  However, if you want to invoke something during run-time, you can use what's called reflection to instantiate objects, or invoke methods at runtime.

http://www.programcreek.com/2013/09/java-reflection-tutorial/ this article may be useful about reflection.